# Binding an attribute to property of the itemssource collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have a data grid.
the item source `MySource` is an `observableCollection<myClass>`.
The class `myClass` has a property `BackgroundOfRow` - its type is `Brush`.

I want to bind the `RowBackground` attribute to this property in the xaml.
how can I do it?

my xaml now is:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ItemSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewModel}, Path=MySource}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" 
                            Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" 
                            FontFamily="Arial" 
                            FontStyle="Italic" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" 
                            Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}"
                            FontFamily="Arial" 
                            FontWeight="Bold" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Do you want to brush your row depends on your Data?

Comment: read this topic and try to catch the base idea.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4ed93258-58b3-48b7-8f73-7a8fd131701f/datagrid-changing-celltemplate-dynamically-based-on-datatype?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `Background` property in the `RowStyle` of `DataGrid`:

**View:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeColl}>
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackgroundOfRow}"/>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

**Model:**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int Surname { get; set; }

    public Brush BackgroundOfRow { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private ObservableCollection<Employee> employeeColl;
public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeColl
{
   get { return employeeColl; }
   set
     {
       employeeColl = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeColl");
     }
}

private void PopulateDataGrid()
{
   employeeColl = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
     if(i%2==0)
        employeeColl.Add(new Employee() { ID = i, BackgroundOfRow = Brushes.CadetBlue});
     else
        employeeColl.Add(new Employee() { ID = i, BackgroundOfRow = Brushes.Green });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it's work! I didn't know to use the row style. you helped me a lot